# Overlay a view in every activity

Tags: android, view, android-activity, overlay

In an app I am working on, I'd like to have a bar with some controls always present at the bottom of the screen. It should overlay every activity in the app but also be able to disappear and reappear. To do this I've considered some options, such as simply using a linear layout and setting the visibility in every activity or using a fragment somehow. Probably those would work but I feel there must be a better solution. So my question is: what is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways you could do this.  You could just use [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html), and make your overlay be a fragment.

The other way would be to sublcass Activity with an AcitivityWithOverlay, which handles the overlay appearing and disappearing then have all of your activities inherit that.  If I did it this way, I'd make my overlay a singleton so I wasn't creating extra versions all over the place that did the same thing.